# Can I add a delay to a schedule in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a pipeline I want to run everyday, but I would like the execution date to lag. That is, on day `X` I want the execution date to be `X-3`. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [TimeSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.sensors.time_sensor.TimeSensor) to delay the execution of tasks in a DAG. I don't think you can change the actual `execution_date` unless you can describe the behavior as a cron.

If you want this to only apply this delay for a subset of scheduled DAG runs, you could use a [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator) to first check if `execution_date` is one of those days you want the lag. If it is, then take the branch with the sensor. Otherwise, move along without it.

Alternatively, especially if you plan to have this behavior in more than one DAG, you can write a modified version of the sensor. It might look something like this:

```
def poke(self, context):
    if should_delay(context['execution_date']):
        self.log.info('Checking if the time (%s) has come', self.target_time)
        return timezone.utcnow().time() > self.target_time
    else:
        self.log.info('Not one of those days, just run')
        return True
```

You can reference the code for the existing time sensor in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/sensors/time_sensor.py#L38-L40.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess this might be the best thing you could do, but that would also mean that a DAG would be in a "waiting" state for X days if I want a delay for X days. Might not be a problem though.

Comment: Apache Airflow introduced a new Operator `DateTimeSensor` which handles some cases where TimeSensor might not be ideal. And then there is also an async version `DateTimeSensorAsync`, which does not take up a worker slot.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using `execution_date` as a variable in your pipeline logic. For example, to process the data that is 3 days older than the `execution_date`. So, instead of making `execution_date` to lag by 3 days you can subtract the lag from `execution_date` and use the result in you pipeline logic. Airflow provides a number of ways to do it:

1. [Templates:](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros) `{{ execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=3) }}`. So, for example, the `bash_command` parameter of BashOperator can be `bash_command='echo Processing date: {{ execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=3) }} '`
2. [The PythonOperator's python callable:](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator) Define the callable something like `def func(execution_date, **kwargs): ...` and set the PythonOperator's parameter `provide_context=True`. The `execution_date` parameter of `func()` will be set to the current execution date (`datetime` object) on call. So, inside `func()` you can do `processing_date = execution_date - timedelta(days=3)`.
3. [The Sensors' `context` parameter](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.html#BaseSensorOperator): The `poke()` and `execute()` methods of any sensor have the `context` paramter that is a dict with all macros including `execution_date`. So, in these methods you can do `processing_date = context['execution_date'] - timedelta(days=3)`.

Forcing execution date to have a lag simply does not feel right. Because, according to the Airflow's logic, the execution date of the currently running DAG normally can have lag only if it is catching up (bakcfilling).

Comment: We are sort of doing what you describe now already. I agree that it might not feel right, but I also don't think it feels right that we run the data for `x-3` on date  `x`. Let's say we want to change the delay, which might happen, we need to remember that every time we want to re-run the data for a specific day. If we could have a lag we would always be able to re-run the same DAG run. At the same time introducing the lag is not ideal either, because then the execution time doesn't reflect when the DAG was run anymore. So both solutions are sort of bad IMO :)

Comment: I agreed with @TomasJansson, both solutions aren't natural. But for me, I think the solution with delay feels better. Because then execution date align with data date and you don't have to think about what the execution date is when you are backfilling.